# Showing that for $n \geq 3$, $Z(D_{2n}) = 1$ for odd $n$ and $Z(D_{2n}) = \{1, r^{\frac{n}{2}}\}$ for even $n$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, dihedral-groups

I am trying to show that for $n \geq 3$, $Z(D_{2n}) = 1$ for odd $n$ and $Z(D_{2n}) = \{1, r^{\frac{n}{2}}\}$ for even $n$. This is my attempt.

> Let $g \in Z(D_{2n})$ and write $g = s^x r^y$ for $x \in \{0,1\}$, $y \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$. If $g$ is in the center, it commutes with $s$:
> \begin{align*}
> s(s^x r^y) & = (s^x r^y)s \\
> s^x (s r^y) & = s^x r^ys \\
> s^x (r^{-y} s) & = s^x r^y s
> \end{align*}
> Cancelling gives:
> \begin{align*}
> r^{-y} & = r^y \\
> (r^y)^{-1} & = r^y
> \end{align*}
> So $r^y r^y = r^{2y} = 1$. $r$ has order $n$, so $n \mid 2y$.

> At this point I should be able to conclude that if $n$ is odd, $2y = 0$, so $y = 0$, but if $n$ is even, $y = \frac{n}{2}$. I cannot figure out how to prove this step, which would complete the proof.

Answer (score 2):

We have $y\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and so $0\leq 2y<2n$. So if $n$ divides $2y$ then we must have $2y=0$ or $2y=n$. If $n$ is odd then only the first option is possible, if $n$ is even then we have $y=0$ or $y=\frac{n}{2}$.

Note that after that you also have to show  that $x=0$, but this is pretty easy.

Comment: The inequality makes sense to me, but I am still having difficulty seeing how $0 \leq 2y < 2n$ implies that $2y = 0$ or $2y = n$. If $n$ divides $2y$, then $2y = mn$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. How would I prove that $m$ has to be $0$ or $1$?

Comment: @Brad G. Because if $m\geq 2$ then $mn\geq 2n>2y$, so in particular $mn\ne 2y$.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The dihedral group has presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^n=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}\rangle.$ It has $n$ involutions $b,ba,\dots , ba^{n-1}$ conjugated by powers of $a$ and $n$ powers of $a$. None of the involutions above is in the center because they do not commute with $a$.

A power $a^i$ of $a$, $0\le i \le n-1$, is in the center iff it commutes with $b$, so iff $ba^ib=a^i$ or $a^i=a^{-i}$ or $i\equiv -i \mod n.$

If $n$ is even then this implies $i\in\{0,n/2\}$ and if $n$ is odd $i=0$. Thus if $n$ is even the center consists of two elements and if $n$ is odd the center is trivial.

Comment: This, to me, is really elegant! (+1)